# Why does a QR Code with a Yourls url go to two different locations?

Tags: qr-code, url-shortener, yourls

I created a qr code with this url generated from yourls installed on my server,

http://transaction-realty.com/yourls/3

which should take the visitor to

https://stackoverflow.com/

but for some people who view it instead of redirecting to where they should, they end up at http://transaction-realty.com/yourls/3 the yourls generation page, without redirecting to the appropriate page.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

qr code with yourls url below

[image]

Comment: Redirect works fine here.  It has nothing to do with the QR code.  If there are redirection issues take a closer look at your server.  And you might want to switch your link... linking to a house for sale can be construed as spam.

Comment: Perhaps some clients don't follow the `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` redirect? Which specific client didn't work?

Comment: @bdares links updated, never even considered the possible spam angle, not sure what I'd be looking for regarding my server, since it works for some people and not others

Comment: sarnold's suggestion seems very plausible..

Comment: @sarnold I'm waiting to hear back from the users who it didn't work for, I know they were both using blackberries, but not sure if the same app

Comment: @Chuck: I've got JaredCo's QR Code Scanner Pro installed on my BlackBerry (which I don't really like, it sure is pushy about needing a lot of permissions) but it redirected to my BlackBerry browser, which Just Worked. It's a small datapoint perhaps...

Comment: @sarnold I ended up using a different script to generate the qr code, and now seems to have no issues, I'm not sure what this script is doing different code wise they look almost identical. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nothing to do with the QR code, and everything to do with the browser that handles the URL. If it did not redirect, then the browser failed to handle the redirect, or it didn't receive it, or it did but was unable to continue to the destination URL.